# Склеить 2 байта little-endian

Tags: теория, байткод, байты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, гугл молчит.
Не нужен код, просто как это сделать правильно?

Мне нужно склеить 2 байта. Порядок байтов - обратный, от младшего к старшему little-endian.

В первом байте содержится информация в HEX-формате: 96.
Во втором байте содержится информация в HEX-формате: 3А.

Какое будет результирующее значение информации? То есть эти 2 байта это же кусочки информации. Какой будет результат, если собрать эти кусочки правильно?

Прилагаю рисунок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 0x96 + 0x3A * 0x100 = 0x3A96

Comment: Извини, друг, за мою неграмотность. Но какой запрос мне гуглить, чтобы понять, что это значит и как с этим работать?

Comment: 96 это младший? Тогда 963А, иначе наоборот 3А96 https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @PHPcrud `3A96` в шестнадцатеричной (`0x` практически в любом языке - префикс шестнадцатеричного литерала), т.е. `14998` в десятичной

Comment: Младший байт впереди. Младший  - 96.

Comment: Эквивалент предложения extrn с битовым сдвигом `0x96 + ((привести тип к 16 битам)0x3A << 8)`

Comment: Задача в чём  - получить Word (uint16) ?

Comment: @MBo, если правда интересно, то опишу.

У меня есть такой пакет информации: 150 58 17 17 4 7 14 – это время 7 байт согласно протокола ГОСТ Р МЭК 870-5-4, тип переменной СР56Время2а.

Я узнал, что 17 17 4 7 14 — время в формате  17 минут 17 часов 04.07.2014.

А вот с первыми двумя байтами вышла засада. 150 и 58 – это 2 байта в DEC-формате (10-ричная система счисления). Переводим эти данные в HEX (16-ричная система счисления):
 150  –>96
 58 –>3A
  Склеим числа 96 и 3A. Порядок следования байтов тут обратный –  little endian. Первым передается младший байт. Надо найти результат склейки

Comment: Ох, не надо ничего переводить. 150 + (58<<8) тот же результат даст. Кроме того, поскольку порядок байт правильный, можно просто интерпретировать этот кусок памяти как word.

Comment: @MBo, из вашей формулы 150 + (58<<8) какой будет результат в миллисеккундах, 14998, как у extrn?

Comment: Да, конечно, числа ведь одни и те же, и умножение  на 256 (0x100) эквивалентно сдвигу на 8 бит.

Comment: Наверно меня не поняли сегодня, когда я дал такой ответ. Завтра буду доказывать, что я не олень)

Спасибо, всем, друзья, не ожидал такой мгновенной поддержки. Очень рад, что тут у нас такое отзывчивое сообщество, помогающее всем развиваться.